# How to remove foreign security principals from my get-adgroupmember output?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to pull up some details of group members, but the group is domain local and contain many foreign security principals. Please advise how to ignore them from my output

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"} 
            -SearchBase "CN=Workstation_LOCAL,OU=Security Groups,OU=Normal Users and Groups,DC=conteso,DC=com" | 
    Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser -Properties * | 
    select name, samaccountname, employeenumber, department, emailaddress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) clause to filter the results. Since you're piping into `Get-ADUser`, you should filter by users, rather than filtering on "not foreign security principal", since groups can contain any AD object (like computers, contacts, or other groups).

It would look something like this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"} -SearchBase "CN=Workstation_LOCAL,OU=Security Groups,OU=Normal Users and Groups,DC=conteso,DC=com" | 
Get-ADGroupMember | Where objectClass -eq user | Get-ADUser -Properties * | 
Select name, samaccountname, employeenumber, department, emailaddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gabriel Luci, your little trick help a lot.

Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupScope -eq "DomainLocal"} -SearchBase "CN=Workstation_LOCAL,OU=Security Groups,OU=Normal Users and Groups,DC=conteso,DC=com" | 
Get-ADGroupMember | Where objectClass -eq user | Get-ADUser -Properties * | 
Select name, samaccountname, employeenumber, department, emailaddress